# remove nan from table data python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I'm using BS4 to pull a table from an HTML webpage and trying to add it to a pandas data frame but it's very sloppy when I pull it and I can't seem to get it to print properly if anyone can help?

There is only 1 table available on the webpage and this is the code I'm using. and what it's pulling.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
df = pd.read_html(str(soup))
print (df)
```

results:

```
[   Unnamed: 0    Student Number     Student Name    Placement Date
0         NaN      20808456          Sandy Gurlow    01/13/2023 
1         NaN            NaN                NaN         NaN]
```

But I've tried to use:

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

And I get the error code:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dropna'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pandas.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) returns a **list** of dataframes, with as many dataframes as it found tables in the input.

You need to use:

```py
df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[0]
```

Or, to avoid IndexError in case of no table:

```py
l = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
if l:
    df = l[0]
else:
    print('no table found')
```

Comment: when I use `df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[0]` I still get the same result when I print it. with all the NAN. and then if I try to use `df.dropna(inplace=True)`  it only prints the headers?

Comment: this means you have too many NaNs and it drops all the rows

Comment: So there isn't really a way to get just the first row without all the useless NaNs?

Comment: @OrbitDuster you have two different questions here, I solved the first one (why you had an AttributeError), the second issue it for now unclear. What would you expect here?

Comment: Was trying to get the header of the table with 1st row. without the NaN's.Header: `Student Number, Student Name, Placement Date` . 1st row: `20808456, Sandy Gurlow,   01/13/2023`

Comment: Maybe try `df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')`, of `df = df.filter(regex='^(?!Unnamed)')`